# Remove ui-state-error cellEditor primefaces

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to put an inputText inside a cellEditor using **validateLongRange** on primefaces like that:

```
<p:contextMenu for="dataTableAvaliacao" widgetVar="cMenu">
    <p:menuitem value="Edit Cell" icon="ui-icon-search"
        onclick="PF('cellNota').showCellEditor();return false;" />     
    <p:menuitem value="Hide Menu" icon="ui-icon-close"
        onclick="PF('cMenu').hide()" />    
</p:contextMenu>  
<p:dataTable 
    id="dataTableAvaliacao" var="aluno"
    value="#{alunoAvaliacaoMB.alunos}"
    editable="true" editMode="cell" 
    widgetVar="cellNota">   
        <p:columns id="coluna-nota"
            value="#{alunoAvaliacaoMB.colunasAvaliacoes}" var="avaliacao"
            columnIndexVar="colIndex" > 
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText
                            value="#{aluno.getNota(avaliacao.property).vlNotaString}" /> 
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">    
                        <p:inputText id="inputNota"
                            value="#{aluno.getNota(avaliacao.property).vlNotaString}">
                            <f:validateLongRange maximum="10" minimum="-10" />                                     
                        </p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>  
                </p:cellEditor> 
        </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

The problem is when validation error occurs, primefaces is painting the inputText and the cellEditor, the appearance looks like that:

[image]

How to remove **ui-state-error** from gridcell?
I have tried using jQuery: **$('.ui-state-error').removeClass('ui-state-error')**
but I don't know where to put it.

I'm using **sentinel-layout**. http://primefaces.org/layouts/sentinel

Sorry for Portuguese words in pictures and code.

**UPDATE**

I can't change the CSS (apparently) because both inputText and cellgrid uses the same style generated by primefaces.

Below two images showing that.

First the style of inputText

[image]

Second the style of gridcell

[image]

How can I change CSS without affect both components?
I'm still looking for a way to remove a class with jQuery. I can remove the style using jQuery.

Comment: @Tiny doesn't work because that style is added dinamically (on blur event, i believe), it's not loaded on begin of the page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thanks for all of your help.

I have solved my problem adding some attributes on style property, like:

```
<p:columns id="coluna-nota" style="height: 25px;width:25px; border: solid 1px #E5EBF0 !important;"
            value="#{alunoAvaliacaoMB.colunasAvaliacoes}" var="avaliacao"
            columnIndexVar="colIndex" >
```

It's not the best way that I would like to do, but was the only that I could solve the problem, probably due to my inexperience in web development :)

Answer (score 3):

A simple way would be to just *override* the style for that particular case with anything default. Then Primefaces can change the styleclass - nobody will notice:

```
td.ui-editable-column.ui-state-error{
   border: 1px solid #dadada !important; // Or whatever is the default color.
                                         // Figure out using inspect element 
                                         // on a non error cell.
}
```

In a nutshell, this style will only be applied, if the style classes `ui-editable-column` AND `ui-state-error` are available on the **same** `td`-tag. Therefore it would not affect the input, because

- Input is no `td`-tag
- Input does not have the `ui-editable-column` class.

See the fiddle: The "double" selector should work perfectly fine for your usecase:

Note, that the one `td` beeing `class="ui-editable-column ui-state-error"` has no red border, even if it should have due to `ui-state-error`.

https://jsfiddle.net/2607kt05/1/

Comment: It's not the way I was expecting, but I will try. Thanks!

Comment: @Johnny, I think the statement in your update is wrong. Try making your selector more specific and it will work I think

Comment: @JohnnyWiller Updated my answer. You can use the double class selector as described. You can add more classes to narrow it down.